# Can you migrate backwards to before the first migration in South?

Tags: python, django, django-south

Can you migrate an app backwards to before its first migration in Django South? If not, are there plans to add such functionality, perhaps using an option passed to `migrate`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
./manage.py migrate myapp zero
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#migrate

In Django 1.11: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Comment: Oh my! Don't know how I missed that. I apparently also missed it in the usage line in `help migrate`. Thank you.